# How to add a collection_select and text_area via JavaScript-function in Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a table where rows and buttons can be added via a button (one for rows, one for columns). The columns consist of one `collection_select` (to select a device) as the title and `text_field` in each row (for test results for this device in each row).
The columns consist of several `text_field` and one `text_area` (for different test specifications).

I use this code to add a column in `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: Testreport.new, local: true) do |f| %>

<table class="table" id="testreport_table">
...
<input type=button id='col_1_button' value="+" onclick="insertColumn();">
...
</table>

function insertColumn() {
          let table = document.getElementById('testreport_table'),
              columns_count = table.rows[1].cells.length,
              rows_count = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
              i;
          document.getElementById('button_row').colSpan = columns_count + 1;
          <% a = f.collection_select( :devicesample_id, Devicesample.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: false, label: "Device Sample") %>
          table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = '<%= a %>'
          for (i = 2; i < (rows_count - 1); i++) {
              table.rows[i].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = "Added Column";
          }
          return false;
      }
```

However, rendering the page throws this error (Chrome): `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

The error is in this generated line:

```
table.rows[1].append('<select name="testreport[devicesample_id]" id="testreport_devicesample_id"><option value="4">Hisense 6486 LATAM</option>
```

Whole generated code:

```
function insertColumn() {
          let table = document.getElementById('testreport_table'),
              columns_count = table.rows[1].cells.length,
              rows_count = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
              i;
          document.getElementById('button_row').colSpan = columns_count + 1;
          table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label for="testreport_devicesample_id">Device Sample</label><select class="form-control" name="testreport[devicesample_id]" id="testreport_devicesample_id"><option value="4">Device A LATAM</option>
<option value="1">Device B </option>
<option value="3">Device C </option></select></div>';
          for (i = 2; i < (rows_count - 1); i++) {
              table.rows[i].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = "Added Column";
          }
          return false;
      }
```

When I just copy the same exact `collection_select` to the regular body, it displays fine. What is causing this error? I have the same issue if I want to add a `text_area`, while `text_field` is working fine.

I am suspecting that it has something to do with the multi-line property of these fields, but even if that is the case I do not know how to avoid this.

I am new to Ruby, Rails and Javascript. I use:

```
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]
Rails 6.0.2.1
Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130
```

(**edit:** replaced `table.rows[1].append('<%= a %>');`with `table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = '<%= a %>'':` which was the original code)

Comment: Check out cocoon gem. It's great for dynamic and nested forms https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: What is the actual desired end result here? Is this supposed to make a form that creates multiple records at once? Since all the inputs here are using the same name attribute they will just overwrite each other and you will only get one in the params hash. If you want to pass an array you need to use `testreports[][devicesample_id]`. https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-build-html-inputs-to-submit-an-array-of-hashes-with-a-rails-form-tag-that-work-with-strong-f70a6c03d78e

Comment: Thanks, it is work in progress. Yes, it is supposed to create multiple records, but that is not implemented yet, because if I can't solve the original issue it makes no sense to put more energy into it, and I will have to look for a completely different solution to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error because you have a multiline string in your code.

So change quotes from

```
table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = '<%= a %>'
```

to

```
table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = `<%= a %>`
```

You can also remove new lines:

```
table.rows[1].insertCell(columns_count).innerHTML = '<%= a.tr("\n","") %>'
```

Of course, it's better to move HTML generation to javascript side, but it's another topic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
submitBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //check to see the answer

    const answer=getSelected();

    if(answer){
        if(answer === quizData[currentQuiz].correct){
            score++;
        }

        currentQuiz++;

    if(currentQuiz < quizData.length){
        loadQuiz();
    }
        else{
            quiz.innerHTML ='
            <h2> you answered correctly at $
            {score}/${quizData.length}
            questions.</h2>

            <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
            ';
        }


        }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).